# Insert value in sqlite database to the first row in a specified column that is null

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert

I'm trying to write a program that will automatically insert a data into a given table in sqlite. Here's how my table looks like:

[image]

For example, I want to input a new value `data5` into col3, here's the command I used:

```
INSERT INTO exam_table (col3) VALUES ('data5')
```

and here's how the table looks afterwards:

[image]

The problem is, if I want to insert a new value into another column, say `col1`, what command should I use so the new value will be inserted into the first row in `col1` that is null (row 2)?

NB: please provide any SQL command except the `UPDATE exam_table SET col1='data6' WHERE col3='data4'`ones, because it's assumed that we don't know how the table looks like, so we **don't know** that 'col3' row 2 contained 'data4'

Comment: If there is no column to order by, "the first row that is null" makes no sense. SQL tables have no concept of order in themselves.

Comment: so you're saying that this is impossible?

Comment: You could put 'data6' in a (pseudo)random row where col1 is null, but not the specific one with 'data4' in it without doing the `where col3='data4'` (or `order by col3`) that you don't want to do.

Comment: well, unfortunately it has to be in the first row in col1 that is null :( is there really no answer for this?

Comment: The problem is similar to "paint the first green car on the parking lot yellow", without saying from which direction to walk. You'll find a first green car from either direction, it may just not be the same car.

Comment: `well, unfortunately it has to be in the first row ` @arranda: you are missing the core point people are trying to make. Rows in a SQL table are in a jumble, like a bag of marbles, unless YOU put them into some arbitrary order by sorting on one or more columns. The physical order of the data represented in your GUI grid is an arbitrary order. Please define "first".

Comment: yes sir, "first" means the first row that is null on that coloumn. i think i have an explanation on the picture. look at the second picture, we can see that column 1 has only one entry + 2 null, column 2 has 1 entry + 2 null as well, and column 3 has 3 entry + 0 null. I want to input data to the column 1, on the first row where its null. I'm just asking if there are any possible ways to do that, sir.

Answer (score 2):

A relational database may not be right for your application, or you may need to explicitly impose ordering on your rows.

You ask:

> *what command should i used so the new value will be inserted into the first row in 'col1' that is null*

... but SQL doesn't have a true concept of row ordering outside of order imposed by queries.  There is no "first row" with a NULL col1 unless you define the scheme to ORDER BY.

You then ask us not to provide an UPDATE command, *"because it's assumed that we dont know how the table looks like, so we **dont know** that 'col3' row 2 contained 'data4'"*

But that is how SQL works:  it conceives of things as unordered sets of tuples (with duplicates permitted).  You don't "insert a value into a NULL field", you INSERT a whole row or UPDATE individual fields.

You must impose ordering and then work from there — and, yes, it will be an UPDATE command or similar — or drop your SQL backend and use something with a different idea of data ontology.